# Making a command executable from a windows command prompt

Tags: windows, variables, environment

I'm being forced to work with a Windows 2003 server machine, and I need to be able to run a BitNami SVN commit hook that'll update a working directory on the same machine.  Because of different users, the script I wrote and tested as working as Admin, doesn't work post-commit.  So I'm trying to make SVN an executable command from any CMD prompt.

Right now, the only way I can do it is by running the batch file that does the following (This is the default BitNami installation batch file):

CALL C:\PROGRA~1\BITNAM~1\scripts\setenv.bat" if not exist
"%USERPROFILE%\BitNami Subversion Stack projects" mkdir
"%USERPROFILE%\BitNami Subversion Stack projects" cd
"%USERPROFILE%\BitNami Subversion Stack projects

START "BitNami Subversion Stack Environment" cmd

The \scripts\setenv.bat file contains this:

set PATH=C:\Program Files\BitNami Subversion
Stack/subversion\bin;C:\Program Files\BitNami Subversion
Stack/sqlite;%PATH%
rem ##### SUBVERSION ENV #####
rem ##### SQLITE ENV #####
rem ##### APACHE ENV #####

So I edited My Computer --> Properties --> Advanced --> Environment Variables
by added these two entries:
C:\Program Files\BitNami Subversion Stack/subversion\bin
C:\Program Files\BitNami Subversion Stack/sqlite

But I still cannot execute a SVN command from a normal command prompt.  So I have two questions, 1 -- how can I make SVN work in this situation from a normal command prompt and 2, can anyone explain the difference between what I've done and what the batch file does?  To my mind at the moment they are the same...although obviously not, since only one works...

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Where does the `svn.exe` executable exist, and is that directory in your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: Hello Greg, it's located in that first entry I made at C:\Program Files\BitNami Subversion Stack/subversion\bin.  And no, it wasn't within the path E.V. adding it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Greg Hewgill pointed out, I had failed to update my PATH environment variable.  Doing this solved my issue -- thanks Greg!